# data.table join with roll = “nearest” returns "search value" instead of original value

Tags: r, data.table

I got a problem with the binary search function `J()` and `roll = "nearest"`.

Let's say I got this example data.table "dt"

```
Key  Value1  Value2
20   4       5
12   2       1
55   10      7
```

I do a search with `roll = "nearest"`:

```
dt[J(15), roll = "nearest"]
```

...which returns:

```
Key  Value1  Value2
15   2       1
```

Thus, the correct row is returned. However, the original "Key" value (12) is replaced by the value used in the search (15).

My question is that a normal behaviour and can one change this auto override?

EDIT:

Reproducible Example (Note I use version 1.9.7):

```
library("data.table")
dt <- data.table(c(20,12,55), c(4,2,10), c(5,1,7))
dt
#   V1 V2 V3
#1: 20  4  5
#2: 12  2  1
#3: 55 10  7
setkey(dt, V1)
dt[J(15), roll = "nearest"]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1: 15  2  1
```

Comment: This is inherited from base R, and is related to [data.table#1615](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1615). If you would provide reproducible example I would try to give you solution...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By reproducible example you mean something like that?

Comment: Yes, just slightly edited for easier copy&paste, it encourages people to answer :)

Comment: @Henrik no point to mention `J()` as this could be also `.()`, `list()` or `data.table()` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need data.table in 1.9.7 to make `x.V1` work. Then you can refer to column from `x` dataset explicitly. This is required because columns used in join are taken from the second dataset `i`, as it is in base R.

```
library("data.table")
dt <- data.table(c(20,12,55), c(4,2,10), c(5,1,7))
setkey(dt, V1)
dt[J(15), .(V1=x.V1, V2, V3), roll = "nearest"]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1: 12  2  1
```

As you mention you already have 1.9.7, for others who doesn't have see [Installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).